# Unproper CSS selector rule?

Tags: html, css

Ok so this is my trouble, I'm tryin' to declare the following CSS rule
`div span > p span + p span {color: green;}`; Or rather said, select a descendant `span` who is an adjacent brother of another `span` (both two last `spans` are descendant childs of a `p` element) of who is in turn a direct child of another `span`, but the most incredible of all this is that the rule `div span> p span` "YES" takes it

Here the "I suppose" proper nesting CSS selectors and HTML code

```css
div span > p span + p span {color: blue;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <p>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </p>
      </span>
     </div>
```

Comment: So are you wanting both of the child `<span>` tags to be blue?

Comment: Your code selects the `<p>` that is an immediate sibling *of the `<span>`* that is a child of a `<p>`. In contrast, you want to select the `<p>` that is an immediate sibling of a `<p>` which contains a `<span>`, not the `<span>` itself. Unfortunately, there is not currently a way in CSS to select a parent that contains a specific child. See: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @TannerDolby no just the last `span`one, nothing else I don't want to write so much

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @showdev, but friend I just want to select the "last descendant `span` child of a `p`, why would I want to select a parent if I know it's not possible?

Comment: In order to select the last descendant `span` child of a `p`, you'd need to determine which `p` elements contain `span` elements. CSS can't do [that](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) [yet](https://caniuse.com/css-has), but [JavaScript can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48564882/924299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a well defined way to select the last descendant of a child element without using JavaScript. But you could try using [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) like this.

```css
div span p:last-child span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <p>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: If the goal is to select the last `span` among all `p > span` pairs, this does not consider those relationships. It selects the `span` inside the last `p` child, regardless of the children of other `p` elements.

Comment: @showdev it's not what I'm searching but your answer is very understandable and I think it makes sense, I'll accept it, take your upvote

Comment: @showdev Yeah I agree. I gave a _broad_ answer that could be tinkered to better select certain pairs. Feel free to propose an edit if you think of a more succinct combinator mix.